# Container div does not grow when child div grows?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the container fit the size of the content when the content size is changes? Notice the background fill does not extend when more content is added.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("content");
text.innerText = document.body.innerText + document.body.innerText + document.body.innerText;;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
 }
 #view1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 671px;
  height: 272px;
  background-color: rgba(232,232,232,1);
  overflow: visible;
 }
 #FlexGroup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 589px;
  left: 41px;
  top: 88px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  gap:  30px;
 }
 #content {
  position: relative;
  align-self: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 590px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Malayalam Sangam MN;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(34,44,65,1);
 }
```

```html
<div id="view1">
 <div id="FlexGroup">
  <div id="content">
   <span>How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: why position:absolute? it's the culprit since it takes the element out of the flow

Comment: even if you change to relative it does not work and keep the top or left positions

Comment: you are also fixing the height of the parent element, so you will have an overflow

Comment: if i remove the height or set it to 100% it does not affect it. the height of the container remains the same if i add content to the content div or not.

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/wo3vn6e9/

Answer (score 1):

Parent element is not aware of its child element if you set `position: absolute` in the child element. So, parent's `height` will not grow as when child element grows. To make it work, you need to set `position: relative` in child element

```js
var text = document.getElementById("content");

 text.innerText = document.body.innerText + document.body.innerText + document.body.innerText+ document.body.innerText;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
 }
 #view1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  width: 671px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(232,232,232,1);
  overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
 #FlexGroup {
  position: relative;
  width: 589px;
    /* height:auto; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  gap:  30px;
    
 }
 #content {
  position: relative;
  align-self: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 590px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Malayalam Sangam MN;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(34,44,65,1);
 }
```

```html
<div id="view1">
 <div id="FlexGroup">
  <div id="content">
   <span>How to make container size to content. How to make container size to content. How to make containntto content. How to make container size to content. How to make</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can remove height in #view1 also remove position: absolute in #FlexGroup

```
    #view1 {
    position: absolute;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    width: 671px;
    background-color: rgba(232,232,232,1);
    overflow: visible;
}
    #FlexGroup {
    width: 589px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: visible;
    gap:  30px;
}
```

Instead of position you can also move your #FlexGroup with margins if you need